# Homeomorphism of two sets

Tags: general-topology

$X $ is a topological space with infinite cardinality which is homeomorphic to $X\times X$.Can we conclude that $X $ is homeomorphic to a subset of $\mathbb R$ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT: Suppose that $X$ is an uncountable space with the discrete topology.

Comment: How is X homeomorphic to X*X with discrete topology

Comment: @learningmaths: Since $X$ is infinite, $X\times X$ has the same cardinality as $X$, so there is a bijection $h:X\times X\to X$. And $X\times X$ certainly has the discrete topology, so $h$ is a homeomorphism.